# Shared Javascript library in Websphere Liberty

Tags: javascript, dojo, websphere-liberty

Can a Javascript library (Dojo, JQuery and/or other personal developed libraries) be used as shared libraries in a Websphere Liberty serve ?

For example, i would like to save the .js in  C:\wlp\usr\shared\resources or C:\wlp\usr\servers\srmtest\resources  and load the library from there in two or three different applications deployed in the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not without writing code. If you write a Servlet that reads files from that location and serves them up then that would work, but Javascript libraries will only be served up from a war file.

If you want to simply share these libraries between multiple applications you could deploy a war file that contains these and just reference it using a different context root for this war.

Comment: Thanks. The objective was to keep it simple to maintain some common libraries that will be used for more than one application and developer, by having one developer just copy toe updated libraries to the common folder and other apps will use them without further intervention.